# Linear interpolation of 2D-arrays along one axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I need to interpolate 2D-arrays along one axis, in this case `axis=1`.
I tried to use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` but I cannot make it work.

This is what I get with a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

xp = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
               [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
yp = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
               [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]])

x = np.array([[1.5, 4.5, 7.5],
              [2.5, 6.5, 9.5]])

interpolate = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xp, yp, axis=1)
    ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.
```

The expected result is:

```
[[ 1.5  4.5  7.5]
 [ 6.5 42.5 90.5]]
```

Of course, the easiest solution would be to iterate along `axis=0` and make several 1D-array interpolations but since my actual arrays are pretty big, I would like to avoid it.
Any idea on how I can solve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can **use scipy.interpolate.interpn**. It's designed for higher dimensional interpolation.

For your example, you would do something like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

interpolated = interpn((xp[0], xp[1]), yp, x, method='linear')
print(interpolated)
```

Result:

```
# [[ 1.5  4.5  7.5]
#  [ 6.5 42.5 90.5]]
```

Comment: your solution is not working for me, I get the error: ```ValueError: There are 11 points and 2 values in dimension 0```